# Wrong hyperlinks of Django Rest Framework with complex stack using SSL, AWS Load Balancer, Nginx and Gunicorn

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, django-rest-framework

I can't find out how to correctly set up `nginx` so my hyperlinks in API build by DRF are correct.

My current configuration for `nginx` is:

```
upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server web:8000;
}

# portal
server {
  listen 8000;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
        proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
}
```

`nginx` is running inside a container exposing port `8000` and maps it into internally running gunicorn (also in a container) also on `8000`. So when I spin up the whole docker machinery, I can nicely access `localhost:8000/api` and links are rendered OK. Even when I access it using different domain (e.g. if I set in `/etc/hosts`: `127.0.0.1 mytest.com`), the URL and port get passed correctly to the DRF and links are rendered as expect.

But this service must sit behind AWS Load Balancer with certificate using SSL. Hostname on this LB is set `otherdomain.com` and it redirects traffic to the machine where the above `nginx` is run using HTTP on port 8000. Then, when try to access it using `https://otherdomain.com/api`, links are rendered as `http://otherdomain.com:8000/api/` <- hence wrong `scheme` (http instead https) and wrong port (8000 instead of 80/443). It make sense, since `nginx` doesn't know anything about the original request coming to load balancer...

None of the ideas I could think of sounds correct. Would greatly appreciate any help. I am willing to change the infrastructure of course.

Any idea how can this be solved?

Comment: Did you add to your `settings.py`.
`SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')`

and 
`SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = not DEBUG`

Comment: That solved that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your `settings.py`.

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = not DEBUG
```

Edit by kotrfa: relevant [part of documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header). I didn't want to add the second line, so it was still possible to access the server directly without HTTPS, e.g. when testing on localhost. For that, I had to set up two different servers in `nginx` - one with hardcoded `Host my.domain.org` on the same port coming from load balancer (e.g. 7779) and then a second with `Host $host:$port` on 7778 so it could be accessed directly behind VPN or on localhost and links still works :-) .